# OpenCV GaussianBlur kernel size 0

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussianblur

As stated in the [opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1),

> ksize – Gaussian kernel size. ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they both must be positive and odd. Or, they can be zero’s and then they are computed from sigma* .

I tried setting kernel size to 0:

```
Mat input = imread(inputImagePath, IMREAD_COLOR);
Mat smooth;
int sigma=1;
GaussianBlur(input, smooth, Size(0, 0), sigma);
```

Which resulted in:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1) in createGaussianKernels
```

It works with `Size(3, 3)`. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Based on the original documentation link... you're using OpenCV 3.4.1, but refer to docs for 2.4.x -- keep in mind that there were some small changes in the API, so it's advisable to refer to the ones that match the version you use. However, as far as I can tell so far, it doesn't seem to be the source of the problem here.

Comment: How did you figure out that the docs are for 2.4? The link indicates 3.4: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1

Comment: Because I read it before approving Dmitrii's edit. | BTW, can you try this with some older release of OpenCV? So far I tried to reproduce it with 3.1.0 which I had on hand, but couldn't reproduce it. It might be a regression, or some recent change that didn't make it to the docs. I interpret the documentation the same way you do, and that just should work (unless I'm also missing something :D ).

Comment: By the look of [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp#L3171) Gerry's code should work. Could it be some unstable build? Try to install opencv from stable channel

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Yeah, I was just looking through that as well, than part hasn't changed in 8 years... Quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the Kernel Size zero. You can make the sigma values as zero. That is why the assertion has failed.

It also important to note that the dimensions of the Kernel should be strictly be odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cv::GaussianBlur(...)` with your kernel in this case **kernel size** in both dimensions must be **odd**: `kernel.width % 2 == 1 && kernel.height % 2 == 1`.

Or you can leave kernel size unset and provide *positive sigma values* (`sigma1` must be set, `sigma2` will be set equal to it by default). If so kernel is computed like:

```
template <typename T>
static void createGaussianKernels( T & kx, T & ky, int type, Size &ksize,
                               double sigma1, double sigma2 )
{
int depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(type);
if( sigma2 <= 0 )
    sigma2 = sigma1;

// automatic detection of kernel size from sigma
if( ksize.width <= 0 && sigma1 > 0 )
    ksize.width = cvRound(sigma1*(depth == CV_8U ? 3 : 4)*2 + 1)|1;
if( ksize.height <= 0 && sigma2 > 0 )
    ksize.height = cvRound(sigma2*(depth == CV_8U ? 3 : 4)*2 + 1)|1;

CV_Assert( ksize.width  > 0 && ksize.width  % 2 == 1 &&
           ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1 );
...
...
}
```

This is from OpenCV 4.1.1 sources. So your code looks pretty valid. I compiled it and it ran without assertion, like it was expected.
Check which version of lib do you use, but that is the very basic functional it hardly was changed recently.

You can also try to provide both `sigma1` and `sigma2` (and use double values to avoid implicit type conversions):

```
double sigmaX = 1.;
double sigmaY = 1.;
cv::GaussianBlur(input, smooth, cv::Size(0, 0), sigmaX, sigmaY);
```